# how to access window property in karma-jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
    angular.module('app').controller('ConvertController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$state', 'toaster', 'StorageManager', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $state, toaster, StorageManager) {
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.init = function() {
        var _authManager = window.client.getAuthManager();
    };
    $scope.init();
    $scope.refreshDataForList = function() {
        $scope.list = userlist.get();
    };
    $scope.searchConversation = function() {
        var data = {
            searchText: $scope.searchText
        };
    };
    $scope.onchange = function(presence) {
        console.log("IN CONTROLLER");
    };
}])
```

I am using karma-jasmine to test my angular app. But while doing testing I am facing problem to access getAuthManager(). It gives error "cannot read getAuthManager() of undefined". However I have included all the files in proper order.

Comment: where you setup `window.client` property?

Comment: in some other file

Comment: an that **other file** is added to karma konfig?

Comment: yes that file is added

Comment: can you show that other file code ?

Comment: there is no window access in karma runner. Also  this is anti-pattern in angularjs. You should inject $window or better, inject your own service for that purpose.